# Deezer API search: weird result in advance search

Tags: api, deezer

I want to use the Deezer API to find a good match for a track using its title & artist, so I tried to use the advanced search described in http://developers.deezer.com/api/search#infos

But this api returns a lot of erratic results. For example:

https://api.deezer.com/search?q=artist:%27jeff%20mills%27 //Completely à côté de la plaque
https://api.deezer.com/search?q=jeff%20mills //Nice

It's pretty weird that when using the advanced search the result is less accurate than without it...

So is there a way to receive an accurate result for a track by specifying the artist and the title?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is not simple quotes that should be used but double quotes, and it works. We will update the documentation about this point, thank you!